# How can I remove ICQ, Yahoo, MSN, Birthday fields from member profile admin in the Controlpanel?

Tags: member-details

Is there a way to remove the silly fields in the member profile administration of the control panel?

If not possible to remove them, is it possible to move them to the bottom so they appear after any custom member fields?

I'm specifically talking about the following fields;

- AOL
- IM
- ICQ
- Yahoo IM
- MSN IM <- this doesn't even exist anymore does
  it?

and ideally I'd like to also remove;

- Birthday
- Location
- Occupation
- Interests
- Bio

Why these aren't an option in the config is something I have never understood. Or, if we want that stuff, just add them as custom member fields.

Comment: Totally agree that these should all be removed by default. They should also be replaced with member fields that can just use custom field types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just knocked up a quick [accessory](https://github.com/tyssen/Remove-Member-Profile-Fields) that does a similar thing to what Matt suggested.

Comment: Now *that's* service! Thank you. I'll give that a go.

Comment: I can see it will work but currently it removes ALL the fields on the profile page :)

Comment: Fixed it... basically $("#aol_im,#icq,#yahoo_im,#msn_im").parents("tr").remove() should be $("#aol_im,#icq,#yahoo_im,#msn_im").parents("p").remove()

Comment: Ah right, sorry, misread your question wrong and thought you meant the register a new member page, not the edit profile page which uses different markup. Just pushed a change that works for both pages.

Answer (score 5):

I would add JavaScript to the control panel - perhaps using http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js

Then the following JS as required (jQuery already included in the CP)

```
$('label[for=aol_im],#other-selectors').parents('tr').remove();
```

You might also have to sort the table row classes (odd/even) but that will remove the fields from users view.

Comment: That might be an option actually. I'm just wanting to hide them since I'm certain my client will say "get rid of those fields please".

Comment: And if you need to do the same for EE1.x there's https://github.com/ninefour/cp_inject.ext.ee_addon

Comment: As jQuery uses CSS style selectors, you can do this in the CSS for the Control Panel as well. Tyssen's accessory below (I haven't tried it) is the smartest route, because you're not hacking EE files.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use this addon http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/disable-default-memberfields

You can select what fields and for who is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are text fields probably, how about use phpMyAdmin to change their labels? Keep the fields short code the same, but just change the label so they appear on the front end as:
Location
Occupation
Interests
That leaves 2 unwanted ones. Rename their labels 'Pinterest' or another popular social media site.

For Bio, make a custom field of text area and for Birthday, make a custom field of date.

That lets you keep things pretty 'stock'.

You'll just need to remember that you assign the field ICQ to whatever you rename it.